# VB Nesting with Else statement for the Main

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, nested

Tried nesting multiple large Sub classes into a Main class with Else statement for the Main (if none of the conditions in the all Sub classes are met, Else statement is invoked ) however the syntax is not working ? (Probably nesting Hierarchy is not correct) 
Appreciate any Advice.Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call public Class  Main
End Sub


Public Class Main

Private Sub Sub_1()

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE1" And ComboBox2.Value = "ANYWHERE1" Then
TextBox1.Value = "Go1"
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE2" And ComboBox2.Value = "ANYWHERE2" Then
TextBox1.Value = "GO2"
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE3" And ComboBox3.Value = "ANYWHERE1" Then
TextBox1.Value = "GO3"
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Sub_2()

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE1" And ComboBox2.Value = "ANYWHERE1" Then
TextBox1.Value = "Go1"
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE2" And ComboBox2.Value = "ANYWHERE2" Then
TextBox1.Value = "GO2"
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "ANYWHERE3" And ComboBox3.Value = "ANYWHERE1" Then
TextBox1.Value = "GO3"
End If

End Sub

Else
TextBox1.Value = "YES"

End Class
```

Comment: You need to work through the basics, or some form of tutorial. You can't nest subs like that and there are no "Sub classes" here

Comment: Do you want to call the method on class?

Comment: This isn't even close to how VB.Net (or any language I've seen) works. This might be a simple misunderstanding of the language constructs coming from another platform, but you may also need to find a basic tutorial first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a serious misunderstanding here about how things work.

Programs contain namespaces. Namespaces contain classes. Classes contain Subs and Functions (and sometimes Events, Enums, Delegates, etc...).  A `Sub` is just a method. It **cannot** exist at the same level as a Class, but rather must be a member (inside of) a class like `Main`. So you can have this:

```
Public Class Main
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        '...
    End sub
End Class
```

But **never** this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    '...
End Sub

Public Class Main

End Class
```

Additionally, Classes exist as a set of methods, fields, and properties. You cannot `Call` an entire class. You can only call specific methods, like a `Sub` or `Function`. When you call a `Sub`, it *only* executes the one `Sub` you call. So this code makes **no sense at all**:

```
Call public Class  Main
```

What you can do is create a variable with a new instance of a class (via the `New` keyword) or use an instance of a class that already exists, and then call a specific method within that class:

```
Dim mainInstance As New Main()
mainInstance.Sub_1()
```

*(In that example, `Sub_1()` might need to be `Public`.)*

Note the `Call` keyword is a throwback from older VB6/vbscript era code. It's not really used anymore for modern VB.Net

There is also a setting somewhere in the Visual Studio solution that tells it what to do when the compiled program first starts up. Often this means calling the `Main` method of the `Main` class, but you can change it to do other things. But the important thing to understand is when the program first runs, some specific method is called, and that determines how control flows through the program. You can also have different method set to respond to events from the user... but in all cases, it's always some specific method (Sub or Function) that is called, and they *always* exists within the context of a class.

Comment: Much Appreciated